# How to join two different cores from two different Solr servers?

Tags: solr

So I have some cores in one solr server and some cores in another solr server and I need to join them.

The schema of the cores are different with no matching attribute name but matching attribute value. I tried to do it with join & shards but both didn't work. Can you help me out?

- `attribute1` is in `abc:7892/solr/core1`
- `attribute2`, `attribute3` is in `xyz:8983/solr/core2`

---

```
{!join from=attribute1 to=attribute2 fromIndex="xyz:8983/solr/core2"} attribute3:*
```

Error Message :

> Cross-core join: no such core xyz:8983/solr/core2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

join does not support joining across different servers, even in SolrCloud mode it has constraints in that sense, see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser).

What you could do is use [Streaming Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions), by using a [search](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions#StreamingExpressions-search) as a source, and then you have several types of joins etc, look at the docs and examples.

Comment: Hi now with SOLR version 8.6.0, it is possible to join between multiple shared and multiple collection. I tried to achieve the same but getting error. Please refer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578595/apache-solr-from-version-8-6-0-joining-between-multiple-collections-and-multip